# What is the basic difference between using NSUserActivity & CoreSpotlight framework for Search programming? How to choose among them?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, corespotlight

How to decide which one is most suitable among CoreSpotlight framework & NSUserActivity for Search Programming.

Comment: Watch the WWDC 2015 video "Introducing Search APIs"-- it gives a great overview and answer to this very question:  https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-709/

Comment: This one is also very helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308

Comment: "Unlike NSUserActivity, Core Spotlight does not require users to visit the content in order to index it"

Answer (score 4):

CoreSpotlight

- does not require users to visit the content in order to index it (index content at any point)
- private on-device index (you don’t use Core Spotlight APIs to make items publicly searchable)

NSUserActivity

- can index only as users perform activities in your app
- public/private indexing
- indexing navigation points

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @sash 's answer, you may want to watch [WWDC 2015 Session 709 Introducing App Search](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-709/)

**The same**

- `userActivity` in `application(_:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:)` has `activityType == CSSearchableItemActionType`
- Utilize `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` to describe attribute

**The differences**

CoreSpotlight

- Intend for indexing many items, making them searchable
- Describe attribute with `CSSearchableItem.attributeSet`
- batching
- update, deleting

> CoreSpotlight is for private data which is indexed on the device and you can use CoreSpotlight to comprehensively index data in your app.
>
> If you're building or you have a social networking app for instance and you wanted to index all of the messages that the user has sent and received, CoreSpotlight is the right tool for the job.

NSUserActivity

- Intent for indexing current activity, making it convenient in Spotlight so that we can pick up
- Describe attribute with `contentAttributes`
- Allow content to be in Apple cloud public in `eligibleForPublicIndexing`

> Use NSUserActivity for both public and private content as well as for indexing navigation points inside of your app.
>
> Now there is another flavor of NSUserActivity that Dave touched on which is Public Indexing.

**More about `NSUserActivity`**

- `becomeCurrent` is for Handoff to start the broadcasting process
- We may use `eligibleForHandoff = false` and `eligibleForSearch = true` to get the nearly same effect as `CoreSpotlight`
- We must keep `NSUserActivity` objects around until the index work finishes
- We don't know when the index work finishes

**Designed to work together**

> These APIs while distinct, they're really designed to work together.
>
> In the same app for the same content you can adopt multiple APIs.
>
> The only thing to remember is for items that are indexed from multiple places, you want to connect these items by giving them the same ID.

More resources

- [App Search Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308)
- [Integrating with iOS System Search](https://realm.io/news/jack-nutting-search-api-ios/)